# How can i deploy Asp.net site with asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a following problem:-

I create a MVC site and deploy on IIS(not in Default Website) with diffrent domain.After that i create a virtual directory(with asp.net site) under same domain , but it is not working because when i open asp.net site it redirect on MVC site and search the controller name with the name of virtual directory which is not in MVC site.How can i solve the Problem.

code of map route method is :

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    "Default", // Route name
        //    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        //    new { controller = "Category", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        //);

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Category", action = "ShowBrand", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the URL requests in global.asax RegisterRoutes method. You'll need to think about how you want MVC to know the difference between a physical URL and a controller request.

Alternatively, you can put redirects in the controller that go to the file locations.